# How to create a new DB with same data from another DB in oracle 10g

Tags: oracle

I trying to copy entire data from old database to newly created database in oracle 10g.
please any one tell me the steps to do the process.

Comment: IMO this belongs on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) or [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/), not on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: Which product & version is your old database?

Comment: You might want to look into Oracle export and import (and latterly data pump). See: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28300/expimp.htm

Comment: Do you have or are you using SQL Developer? It has a "Data Pump Wizard" which could be a very easy way to get this done. See http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sql-developer-31-data-pump-wizards.php for a step-by-step guide.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to user RMAN's [Duplicate Database](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14191/rcmdupdb.htm#BRADV169) feature.